# What properties are defined on the event passed to an AWS appspec lambda hooks function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

An AWS codedeploy lambda hooks function accepts three parameters:

`exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks-section-structure-ecs-sample-function

But what properties are available to me on these objects? The example shows the event defines at least DeploymentId and LifecycleEventHookExecutionId but what else can I extract? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, I have found that only the fields `DeploymentId` and `LifecycleEventHookExecutionId` are included on the event. I don't know what fields are included on the other parameters.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this either.